# Give files user permissions

Tags: permissions, scripts

I'm having a hard time solving this problem.

write a shell script to check the executable rights for all the files in the current directory. if the file doesn't have the user executable right then make it user executable.

I was thinking if looping on all the files in the current directory and writing the output to a text file. then reading the fourth character of every line and check whether it's 'x' or '-'

Comment: You should look into text manipulation and looping through bash.  You can look for 'rwx' or look at the integer of the permission.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea you have seems legit but unnecessarily large and complex, rather you can use this:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
for file in *; do
    [[ -x $file ]] || chmod u+x "$file"
done
```

- This will read all files (`*`) in the current directory
- Then it will check if the file is executable by the user running the script (`[[ -x $file ]]`)
- If not (`||`), it will make the file executable for the user (`chmod u+x "$file"`).

By default `*` will not match hidden files, to match hidden files also add the line

```
shopt -s dotglob
```

after the shebang line.

If you want to search and operate on only regular files:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
for file in *; do
    if [[ -f $file ]]; then
        [[ -x $file ]] || chmod u+x "$file"
    fi
done
```

Comment: for file in *.* will only take into consideration the files right ?

Comment: @WassimSeifeddine use the last script i have given...it will only consider files..`for file in *` will consider whatever there in the directory (can be files, directories, links etc)....the checking `[[ -f $file ]]` will ensure that we are taking only the files....

Answer (score 1):

It's a simple `find` command with `chmod`:

```
find . -type f ! -perm -u+x -exec chmod u+x {} \;
```

or only for the current folder:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f ! -perm -u+x -exec chmod u+x {} \;
```

---

*Explanation*

- `.`

  Start the search in the current folder
- `-maxdepth`

  Not recursive
- `-type f`

  Only files, no folders
- `! -perm -u+x`

  Only files without the executable flag for the owner of the file
- `-exec chmod u+x {}`

  Set the executable flag for the owner of the file

Comment: +1 but you have a typo in the first command, the `!` operator should be before `-perm -u+x`

Answer (score 0):

I wish you had mentioned if it is a part of a bigger automation project or simply something you wanna do.

You can simply do the following in a directory:

```
chmod u+x *
```

This adds executable status to all files inside a folder for "*your user*". You can try to add it for "*everyone*" by

```
chmod a+x *
```

Note, your user should have permission to change files inside that specific folder. It means you should have '*write*' permission. Otherwise, you won't be able to change anything. If your user is administrator, you can invoke it with the `sudo` command:

```
sudo chmod a+x *
```

If a file already has executable status, there is no harm in giving it the status again. Of course, as I said, unless you want to use the name of all files whose status is changed for another purpose, e.g. reporting. heemayl's script is a nice thing, for such purposes.

---

*Added from  Mostafa Najafiyazdi comments*

[..] if he doesn't want to touch permission of folders which have no executable permission, he should not use `chmod u+x *` [..]

Comment: Only files not files and folders.

Comment: I believe `chmod` without the switch `-R` will not change folder's status! :)

Comment: `chmod u+x *` affects files AND folders.

Comment: I believe folders by default have -x for the user, group and everyone!  I just created a folder and looked at its permissions.

Comment: That may be, but it need not be so. Maybe someone has intentionally changed the permissions and perhaps this someone wants that it stays that way.

Comment: That totally makes sense. That's why I have explained if it is a simple thing he wants to do. But you are right, if he doesn't want to touch permission of folders which have no executable permission, he should not use `chmod u+x *`